# Powershell Delete for all AD users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, system-administration

I am trying to delete a file across all of the devices at our company. I am trying to get a list of the computer names and then a list of user names. Here is what I have created so far. We have organized our users to their initials which is why I am only keeping the first 3 characters. In this case, I am just trying to see if the path exists for each user.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this or what I should put in the "user" directory path. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
$ComputerList = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).name
$ComputerName.Substring(0,3) = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).name
Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList)
{
$checkpath = 'C:\Users\ \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Login Data'
Test-Path -Path $checkpath
}
```

Comment: I would recommend not trying to script this and instead use Group Policy.

Comment: I was exploring this too but wasn't sure how I would set it up in GP. Any tips?

Comment: A question about how to use GPOs is probably more appropriate for serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Get-ChildItem on each device so it will only find the users that have actually logged into that device. You can then use the .fullname of each ChildItem to get the full path, e.g. "C:\Users\username"

```
Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList)
{

    $userfolders = get-childitem C:\users\
    foreach ($user in $userfolders) {
        $path = $user.fullname
        test-path -Path "$path\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Login Data"
    }

}
```

This will go through each computer in the list, find which user folders exist on each machine, and then test each of those for the path.

EDIT: Not thinking clearly... The path for get-childitem needs to be like this:

```
$userfolders = get-childitem "\\$Computer\C$\users\"
```

Otherwise it will just keep checking your own machine's C:\ drive repeatedly

Comment: Thank you! Haha, yes I figured out the last edit after I initially tried it. Appreciate all you help.